# Clique number of a generalized Johnson graph $J(n, k, k/2)$

Tags: combinatorics, algebraic-graph-theory

The generalized Johnson graph $J(n,k,r)$ is defined to be the graph whose vertex set is the set of all k-element subsets of ${1,2,…,n}$, and with two vertices adjacent iff their intersection has exactly r elements. Now, is there some upper bound for the clique number of $J(n,k,k/2)$? It should be bounded by $n$ or something close to.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/648956/5676) (almost a special case, although not quite).

Comment: I have seen that post. Here $k$ does not depend on $n$, plus something more...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Represent the vertices by $01$-vectors of length $n$, each with exactly $k$ entries equal to 1. Let $C$ be a clique. I claim that the vectors representing the vertices in $C$ are linearly independent, whence it follows that $|C|\le n$.

To prove the claim, let $G$ be the Gram matrix of the vectors belonging to $C$. If $J$ is the all-ones matrix, we have
\[
   G = \frac{k}2(I+J)
\]
and since $I+J$ is invertible, $G$ is invertible and therefore it is the Gram matrix of a linearly independent set of vectors.

Comment: Thx. It seems that the bound is attained for $n=3, k=2$. Otherwise, it is $n-1$ (I am not sure).